# I cannot find full Sentinel-2 scenes

Tags: image, download, image-service, sentinel-2

I want to download Sentinel-2 images of "Navarra" zone from June to December of 2016. I want to download all swith image (all tiles in a SAFE file) but when I search this I only can download up to September; from October onwards  I only can download single tiles.

Do you know how many time has to be passed to get the whole image?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I acknowledge in advance that the following links don't provide you with direct access to the full scenes, but I do think that they are useful resources for searching the Sentinel-2 archive. In particular, the [Sentinel-2 on AWS](http://sentinel-pds.s3-website.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/#ImagerySearch) portal and it's [associated browser](http://sentinel-pds.s3-website.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/browser.html) provides you with an efficient viewer.

[image]

In addition, the above portal, provides you with a set of other links that can be used to access/download Sentinel-2 data.

Answer (score 6):

As far as I know, only tiled scenes are distributed since october on the ESA hub, so you will need to download all the tiles. Note that there are several alternative websites to download S2 data with more options. Because you are close to France, you could be lucky to have preprocessed images from [CESBIO](https://www.theia-land.fr/en/news/sentinel-2-level2a-products-distribution-schedule)

Answer (score 3):

Not a proper answer either, but RemotePixel's 'Satellite Search' tool does offer another alternative viewer/downloader to get single band jp2 tiles (via Amazon Web Services). You can find it at https://remotepixel.ca/projects/satellitesearch.html. Note that you have to toggle between Landsat 8 and Sentinel 2 to get the right satellite.

[image]

There's also some other download tools/APIs to get single tiles you can find on Github such as https://github.com/kalxas/Sentinel-download and https://github.com/sat-utils/sat-download (which is a part of Development Seed's sat-utils https://github.com/sat-utils). Mostly python-based ones mind you. I think all of them offer metadata downloads in the form of json files, but I'm not sure if that will fit with your workflow.